# Selenium Webdriver takes long time to run

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver taking a long time to run than ide why, is there a way to execute my web driver example in already opened firefox browser, Since I was new to Webdriver I need good tutorials, Please share the examples of whatever u have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to work on it and learn as you work.  Write a simple code, understand it, add complexities and figure out how to solve.

A tutorial can only help you get started. 
 To that end, a good starting point can be http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp.
Use the sample codes there to start off.

Other good resources are :
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps

And nope, you cannot execute your test in an already opened browser.

Hope it helps.